# Blocked system call doesn't let SIGKILL kill the process

Tags: c, linux, kernel, block, system-calls

I have a query regarding propagation of signals between kernel threads.
The scenario is like this:

From a user space app, a system call is made, the kernel creates a thread (lets name it thread1)inside the system call.

Now inside that thread1, the kernel is looping in a while loop and it is blocked. The main thread is also looping in a while loop. 
If I do a “kill -9 <"user app pid>”, the application is not able to exit properly. Even the /proc entry still exists.
Although the /proc//fd folder becomes empty.

If I put following in the main thread’s while loop, it catches the signal properly and exits. If I put following only in the thread1’s while loop, the main thread still doesn’t exit.

```
if (signal_pending(current)) {
  return;
}
```

Can you please suggest, how the kernel should behave in this case of kill -9 signal? After the SIGKILL, the process's state become Zombie.

The system call has following implementation:

```
thread1 = kthread_create(thread_fn, NULL, "thread1");
if (thread1) {
    wake_up_process(thread1);
}
printk(KERN_NOTICE "Main thread: current:%s\n", current->comm);
while(1) {
    DELAY_SEC(1)
```

The thread_fn is:

```
int thread_fn(void* data)
{
    while(1) {
        DELAY_SEC(1)
   }
}
```

Regards,

Sonika

Comment: How do you create the process, that remains as a zombie?

Answer (score 3):

Sending a signal to a process just sets a respective flag for this signal.

When a process returns from kernel mode (e.g., when a system call returns), these flags are checked. If one of them was previously set, the respective action is taken.

Since your system call never returns, this does never happen.

In other words: You cannot really kill a Linux process. You can just politely ask it to die.